# How to access a custom config from my class library application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, configuration, web-config

I have a custom config in my Infrastructure Project, but when my app start only my web.config is recognized.

I don't want to place the configuration of this custom config file in my web.config because this configuration is responsability for Infrastructure Layer.

How I use this custom config from another project in my web project?

Comment: What kind of infrastructure configuration do you have that the web application shouldn't know about?

Comment: @Harper is settings about path of files that user will save in app;

Comment: OK - so it's internal application configuration, but not really "infrastructure". That really sounds to me like stuff that does belong in web.config. I normally create a custom configuration section for things like that, though, so you don't end up with all sorts of crazy appSettings keys.

Comment: @Harper Web.config is in my UI layer, this things do not belong in UI layer.

Comment: web.config is a configuration file - it's accessible by *all* layers. The fact that it resides in the 'UI' project is an implementation detail, not a declaration of what it is.

Comment: @Harper I don't agree. If tomorrow I want to change the UI, or put another UI, I will must to do another config file?

Comment: No. Especially not if you use a custom configuration section, a little build process magic, and potentially an included config file for your custom section. You are focusing far too much on the implementation details. Yes, the web.config file lives in the UI layer. Does that mean that a new UI will force you to create a new web.config (or app.config)? Yeah, but you don't need to repeat all the common configuration if you use the other facilities of your dev/build systems to avoid that repetition.

Comment: @HarperShelby I think I understand. Can you explain more when you say: "You are focusing far too much on the implementation details."?

Comment: Sure. In a Visual Studio solution, the web.config (or app.config) file lives in the UI project. Because of the existing VS build process, this is something you probably won't change. However, the configuration file is for the application, not for any particular logical layer of the application. You can tweak the build process so that specific configuration information is stored in a separate file that can be referenced from the final web.config without being a part of it, or (in 2010), you can create web.config transforms that the build process uses to customize configs. Those are just details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answers to this question are failing to inform you of a critical point.

.NET is designed to have a single configuration process for each `AppDomain`. All class libraries will use the configuration file of the application which calls them. In your case, your class library will use the web.config. If your class library were being used from a console application, then it would use the *application*.exe.config file.

When you think about it, this is the only thing that makes sense. If your class library is used from two separate applications, then it will have two separate configurations. These configurations *must* be managed on behalf of the calling application.

Comment: Look at my situation, I need to a custom config file to set paths where will be save files. Web.config live in UI Layer, are you sure?

Comment: If your class library is being called from a web page, then yes, it needs to be in web.config. It's not a question of layers. It has nothing at all to do with layers. It has to do with which file needs to be modified to change the configuration. .NET makes configuration _much_ easier by requiring one file per _application_, not one file per component, as with .ini files or the Registry.

Comment: You have a source where say .NET is designed to have a single configuration process for each *AppDomain*?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229689.aspx: "The name and location of the application configuration file depend on the application's host, which can be one of the following"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var exeMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap {ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\Path\To\Your\File"};
Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    exeMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None
);
```

Comment: Exist another more simply way?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `<appSettings file="foo.config">` method, but then you can only use a relative path to the other file. That's normally used to organize app settings and configuration strings.

Comment: I know this approach but i don't want to use them too. I see custom configuration files of another libraries like log4net a lot, I don't know how they use it.

Comment: nHibernate also uses that kind of setup, but they wrote their own configuration framework.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the infrastructure project is a class library, have you considered creating properties to expose the app.config (?) settings to the front-end?

Here is an example of what I mean. Keep in mind that this is just an example. It's a property that demonstrates how to expose a config value through a property. In your case, the property would retrieve a value from your custom config file.

```
public string GetConfigurationValue(string Key)
{
    return GetValueFromConfiguration(Key);
}
```

One thing I'm wondering is why you're creating a custom configuration file rather than just creating a configuration section that you can integrate into the app.config file. It seems like you're making things much more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: is not app.config, is a custom config. yes, to create a custom config i need to create a class derived from ConfigurationSection. You mean get values directly from class instead to get values from the config file?

Comment: No, I mean create public properties that retrieve the values from your config file, so the web application using the library can use the properties to access the config values.

Comment: -1: why does your example use `WebConfigurationManager`? That would limit the code to being called from ASP.NET.

Comment: I stated very clearly that it was an example, and that it would be different for his implementation. It was meant to demonstrate the concept of exposing config values through a property.  Honestly surprised that you would downvote this. I feel like you didn't read my answer.

Comment: I did read the comment, and I know his particular example, but I feel that when someone comes to this answer looking for config file info in general, your example gives the wrong idea.